# The top app bar not disappearing in Lollipop - API 21

Tags: android

I wrote the styles in values-v21 and also included the themes
in the Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".events"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_events"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

In the styles.xml of values-v21 I am writing-:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Still the top action bar is not disappearing in API - 21 although it is disappearing in API<=19

Can somebody tell where is the folly.

Comment: `<style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">`

Comment: Are you able to figure out answer? Or still need helps?

Comment: Thanks sir actually the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it Programatically:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: Also you may be missing the parent attribute as suggested by @IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the parent to `Theme.AppCompat`

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Hope this helps.